# Twilio Not doing anything when receiving SMS

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I'm creating a sample application that will post alerts to the website in the event of a hurricane or service outage. I'm not using Laravel.

I set the URL of the page in my account settings. The first time I sent a message I received a HTTP error that it had timed out without being given a reponse. I edited the XML and tried again.

I'm not getting anything in the database and I'm not getting the response. I also wrote a sample page that posts a value to see if it would work and it did. It posted it into the database and showed correctly formatted XML.

```
<?php
$response = 'This number cannot handle automated replies...';
$twiml1 = '<response><sms>';
$twiml2 = '</sms></response>';
require_once '../settings/db.php';
if (isset($_POST['body'])) {
    $body = strip_tags($_POST['body']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO alerts (message) VALUES ('$body')";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    if ($result) {
        $response = 'Thanks. Your message was posted on the website.';
    } else {
        $response = 'There was a query error.';
    }

}
header('Content-type: application/xml');
echo $twiml1;
echo $response;
echo $twiml2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Parameters that are sent via webhooks from Twilio are case sensitive and start with a capital letter. The text for an incoming message is sent as the `Body` parameter so checking for `$_POST['body']` won't work.

I'd update your conditional to:

```
if (isset($_POST['Body'])) {
    $body = strip_tags($_POST['Body']);

    // The rest
}
```

Also, just to note, the `<Sms>` element has been deprecated. I'd use the [`<Message>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message) element instead. The tags are case sensitive too, so I'd update the TwiML section to this:

```
$twiml1 = '<Response><Message>';
$twiml2 = '</Message></Response>';
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Sweet! Would you mind marking the answer as correct so that if others come across this it's easy to see it helped. Thanks!

Comment: Done - that was my first time on Stack Overflow - didn't know. Maybe in a year I'll be using Laravel. I'm a student...

Comment: Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow! I hope your programming journey goes well 